# Automate a gratuitous ARP every x seconds

Tags: linux, networking, centos, virtualbox, arp

There may be another issue here, so any other questions or comments are welcome.

I have a CentOS 6.6 VM running under VirtualBox. It is connected to a GNS3 topology using a UDPTunnel. Everything works, but eventually the ARP entry for the default gateway goes stale and doesn't refresh. If I manually do an arping, it starts working again, but only temporarily.

Other than the obvious cron job or continuous ping, is there a way to automate gratuitous arp replies in CentOS?